Is writing articles/blogs still relevant in the age of AI?
People around me and I use AI like ChatGPT to get information on the internet. If we don't find the accurate data about what we are looking for, only then we search on Google and copy the content of articles we think is what we want and paste that content on ChatGPT and ask for the essence of those articles or summarize it.

Do you guys think writing articles and publishing on websites is a good idea?
I know that the data these AI provide are also fetched through the content we publish, but the thing is, if we write a well written content and most of the readers might read the essence of it using GenAI, as people now don't want to give any efforts and they want quick results, what would be the relevance of these articles in the future?
Why would someone write a well written content if they knew people would only read the summarized version of it?
People busy scrolling short format videos on social media, they consume much of news, current affairs, information from these videos mostly.

Do you think writing articles has the potential to influence people like it has done over the years?

This presupposes a level of gen AI usage that is clearly not actually real. That, or seems just a rant of the "people nowadays..." variety which tend to happen every nowadays.

You're on a website about the craft of writing, where AI-generated content is strictly forbidden. What kind of answers and/or general reaction are you expecting here?

By the way, if you are relying on “AI like ChatGPT to get [reliable] information,” you are being woefully malnourished. The AI summaries typically offered, for instance, in reply to Google searches are very, very often misleading. Sometimes subtly so, sometimes severely so.

I suggest you ask the AI a question about things you already know.  By comparing what you know with what the AI delivers, you can see just how crummy the AI answers are.


as people now don't want to give any efforts and they want quick results

You should back up that claim.
With new reasoning models out now (which are, for other reasons, terrifying), I occasionally use LLMs for solving some equations when I’m too tired to (and fact-check afterwards). But knowing a lot of other people and their social habits, I will tell you that the usage of AI summarization, while existent, is not nearly as widespread as “people nowadays” makes it seem.
Generated summarizations are getting more accurate, this is true. But a person who would rather summarize a text and read three bullet points instead of the whole text itself is hardly a person I would want to write for. Besides, is the point of writing articles to be read or to add to humanity’s knowledge? Either way, writing an article (AI or no AI) is a good idea.
